# How to select textual columns of a table with the information about the longest string in them

Tags: mysql

I am selecting columns like this:

```
    SELECT table_name, column_name
    FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE table_schema ='db_name' 
      AND data_type IN ('varchar', 'text') 
      AND table_name='table_name';
```

The result is a table name and column name on each row. In the third column I would like to see a number of bytes of the longest string in that column of the table.

I am trying to optimize a table becouse when I am trying to convert data from latin2 to utf8 I get the "Row size too large." error. So I want to change varchar (255) to lower number if possible. I would like to avoid changing columns to TEXT if it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql function you are looking for is the `length()` function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Combined with `max(length(COLUMN_NAME))` and a `group by` statement, you should be fine.

Comment: I know these functions and the group by statement too. The problem is how to combine them with the query I posted :) Using Join? or Concat?

Comment: I've never querried the `information_schema` table but I would assume you can just add `max(length(COLUMN_NAME))` as your third column with `group by table_name`, column_name` at the end.